I got error 404 after payment success through PHONEPE
I am implement phonepepayment sdk in iOS swift project for phonepe payment gateway and I successful implement that but after the payment success when they need to go to redirect or callback link they don't go and give error 404 page in phonepe sdk
I an using this code
by forcefully cut the phone after the error 404 it goes to failed case but payment is deducted from the user end
how to solve that and who is involved to this issue
func startPayment(merchantTransactionId: String, callbackUrl: String,amount:Int,mobileNumber:String,merchantUserId:String,merchantId:String) {
        let payload = """
        {
            "merchantId": "\(merchantId)",
            "merchantTransactionId": "\(merchantTransactionId)",
            "merchantUserId": "\(merchantUserId)",
            "amount": \(amount),
          "callbackUrl": "\(callbackUrl)",
            "mobileNumber": "\(mobileNumber)",
            "paymentInstrument": {
                "type": "\(paymentInstrumentType)"
            },
        "redirectUrl" : "\(callbackUrl)",
        "redirectMode" : "POST"
        }
        """
        let base64EncodedString = Data(payload.utf8).base64EncodedString()
        let checksum = sha256(base64EncodedString + apiEndPoint + salt) + "###" + saltIndex
        let headers: [String: String] = ["X-VERIFY": checksum]
        let request = DPSTransactionRequest(
            body: base64EncodedString,
            apiEndPoint: apiEndPoint,
            checksum: checksum,
            headers: headers,
            appSchema: "" // Your app's URL scheme
        )
        PPPayment(environment: .production, enableLogging: true, appId: phonePeAppId)
            .startPG(transactionRequest: request, on: self, animated: true) { _, result in
                print("result is this : \(result)")
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    print("Transaction successful: \(result)")
            
               case .failure(let error):
                    print("Transaction failed: \(error)")
                    self.dismiss(animated: false)
                case .interrupted(_):
                    print("Payment interrupted")
                @unknown default:
                    print("Unknown error")
                }
            }
    }

